# Setting up ScyllaDB + Janusgraph + Tinkerpop

Tags: debian, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, scylla

About to start using **ScyllaDB** with **JanusGraph**, and **Tinperpop3**.

For now, I'll work with <200 gb data, so I want to do everything on my own (xeon based) computer.

My question is mostly: are some versions incompatible with each other?

For **ScyllaDB** I'd probably go with:
https://www.scylladb.com/download/debian9/

But **JanusGraph** does not list ScyllaDB as (tested and) compatible, although I've read on several places this can be used
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.2.2

And for **Tinkerpop3**, I'd go with their latest version 3.3.4
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most up-to-date version of JanusGraph is 0.3.1 which packages Apache TinkerPop 3.3.3. You do not need to download TinkerPop separately. https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.3.1

From a JanusGraph perspective, ScyllaDB is a drop-in replacement for Cassandra. You [configure](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/cassandra.html) your graph properties in the same way using `storage.backend=cql`, but just point it at your ScyllaDB server instead. Keep in mind if you're using the pre-packaged JanusGraph distribution, you need to shutdown Cassandra before starting ScyllaDB to avoid port conflicts.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I am relatively new, apologies for asking obvious questions, but how does this work with ScyllaDB? Should I just first install Scylla, and then proceed to your link, will this work? Do I need to configure (many) things?
Thanks again!

Comment: Also, is it possible to download Janusgraph 0.3.1 without Tinkerpop 3.3.3 in order to be able to separately download TP 3.3.4?

Comment: From a JanusGraph perspective, ScyllaDB is a drop-in replacement for Cassandra. You [configure](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/cassandra.html) your graph properties in the same way using `storage.backend=cql`, but just point it at your ScyllaDB server instead. Keep in mind if you're using the pre-packaged JanusGraph distribution, you need to shutdown Cassandra before starting ScyllaDB to avoid port conflicts.

Comment: In general, you should keep the TinkerPop version aligned with the version shipped with JanusGraph. TinkerPop is a core dependency, so if you really want to update the version, you should update the version in the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.3.1/pom.xml#L72) and [build the distribution](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.3.1/BUILDING.md#building-janusgraph) from source code. Is there a specific bug fix you require from TinkerPop 3.3.4?

Comment: Thanks! Regarding Scylla: I've never used Cassandra either, I'm just starting out, all three of the components are new to me. And regarding the Tinkerpop version: I was simply thinking about always going with the latest version, but no other reason than that.

Comment: Apologies for bothering you, but what should I download? I am not sure how to use the .asc and keys but would want to verify the download. Many thanks for any tips!

Comment: The pre-packaged JanusGraph distribution is `janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2.zip`. Make sure you import the public `KEYS` file into your GPG keyring first: `gpg --import KEYS`. Then you can validate the distribution against the `*.asc` file: `gpg --verify janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2.zip.asc janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2.zip`.

Comment: Thank you. I had already unzipped  `janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2.zip`
I did follow your instructions now and got: 
`gpg: Good signature from "Jason Plurad (CODE SIGNING KEY) <pluradj@apache.org>" [unknown] gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature! 
 gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.`
This sounds like a problem, but I'm not sure. There is also a `Primary key fingerprint`.

Comment: There is also a doc which might be helpful: https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: The GPG signature is good, as the message states. If the signature was not valid, you would have seen an error rather than "Good signature". The warning is because my key is not (yet) part of the [Web of Trust](https://wiki.apache.org/apachecon/PgpKeySigning).